# Pytorch transformer: What does "tgt" parameter do if num_decoder_layers = 0?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, transformer-model

If I make no decoder layers in my transformer like this:

```
nn.Transformer(nhead=1, num_encoder_layers=1, d_model=1, dim_feedforward=1, num_decoder_layers = 0, dropout=0)
```

Why do I need to pass in "the sequence to the decoder" during the forward pass of the model? What does tgt do?

Answer (score 1):

By looking at the source code I found that nn.Transformer calls nn.TransformerDecoder. Looking at the implementation of TransformerDecoder, it appears tgt is directly returned if no decoder layers